# Excluding the '#recycle' directory from s3cmd upload

Tags: linux, amazon-s3, s3cmd

I'm using `s3cmd` on a Synology NAS.

I built an exclusion file including `#recycle/*` and the `--exclude-from=/path/to/exc/file` option but it doesn't work.

I already tried this: `'#recycle/*'`, `"#recycle/*"` and `"\#recycle/*"` but s3cmd still tries to upload the '#recycle' folder contents.

I have an error when trying to using both `--exclude from=/path/to/file` and `-exclude='#recycle/*'` in the same command.

Any ideas?

Comment: So far I tried: `"#recycle/*"
"*/#recycle/*"
"/volume1/JOB/#recycle/*"
"*/JOB/#recycle/*"
"/JOB/#recycle/*"
"/volume1/JOB/#recycle"
"#recycle/"
@eaDir/*`...same problem.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should probably use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question. There are more appropriate sites available to help with Amazon commands.

Comment: Yes, I realise that now. Thank you jww.

Comment: Yeah, Stack Overflow does not do a good job at educating new users. They don't clearly state what Stack Overflow is for; and they don't show you other sites available to you. They set you up for failure, and it sours your experience. Just remember, it is not your fault. It is Stack Overflow's fault.

Comment: Well I posted the question on serverfault, I'm not sure I should delete this one..Any way thanks for taking the time.

Comment: I personally like [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/). Your mileage may vary. If you get a cold welcome at [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/), then delete the question and ask at SU or U&L. (SF has a "professional admin" requirement, and they can be rough on developers. I personally avoid SF, even when using my old MCSE for admin stuff).

Comment: Thanks, my problem might also relate to Linux as it may be parsing the `#` that causes the issue.